# Use Haxe API classes explicitly

Tags: javascript, api, math, haxe, phaser-framework

I use Haxe targeting Javascript.

I have a package (defined as an extern), "`phaser`", that contains a `Math` class along with many others.
I use `import phaser.*;` at the beginning of my files because I use many classes from this package and I don't want to prefix them all with `phaser.`.

I would like to use [the Math class from Haxe API](http://api.haxe.org/Math.html), but if I try to use it (e.g `Math.random()`), the compiler thinks I want to use `phaser.Math` and tells me there is no such function in it.

Can I explicitly write that I want to use *Haxe* `Math` class and not `phaser.Math` ?

I've tried `haxe.Math` but no luck...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
import Math as HaxeMath;
```

then use `HaxeMath.*` instead of `Math.*`

Note, nothing special about the name `HaxeMath`, you could do

```
import Math as Freddy;
```

then use `Freddy.*` instead of `Math.*`. :p

Comment: Thanks! Even `import Math;` works and grants higher priority to haxe `Math` over Phaser's, I just didn't think I needed to import it...

Answer (score 4):

Two ways to solve it:

1. Use `std.Math`. e.g. `std.Math.floor(1.1);`, or `typedef HxMath = std.Math;`, or
2. Add `import Math as HxMath;` before `import phaser.*;`. If you're using a haxe version earlier than 3.2, use `in` instead of `as`, i.e. `import Math in HxMath;`.

Comment: Thanks, std.Math is exactly what I was looking for. It doesn't appear in autocompletion...