# Force compiler to treat identifier as package name

Tags: macros, haxe

TestApi Class:

```
package api;
class TestApi {}
```

AnotherClass

```
package somewhere.else;
class AnotherClass
{
    var api:SomeType;

    function problem()
    {
        api.TestApi; 
        // Compiler error: SomeType has no field TestApi


    }
}
```

In the example above, I want to force the compiler to treat `api` as package name instead of a variable, so that `api.TestApi` refers to the class but not a member of the `api` variable. I need to do this because I am building the expressions inside macro and not able to use import statements. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to solve this with the pseudo package `std`, which resolves to the API root: ([1](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/haxelang/GzAWc7xix5E/gdHL26Ge2QMJ))([2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31222421/2801377))

```
var api:SomeType;
function problem() {
    std.api.TestApi;
}
```

Another example:

```
class Test {
    static var Test = 42;
    static function main() {
        trace(Test);           // 42
        trace(std.Test.Test);  // 42
    }
}
```

([see it in action](http://try.haxe.org/#199aF))

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it worked. But the problem still exists if the variable name is "std". I think a metadata should be introduced for this.

Comment: @KevinResoL I suggest you to open a feature request issue on the official repository.